# SQL count how many records are between two dates and return that count

Tags: mysql, date, count

I want to thank those who have help me recently. I'm getting really close to my goal but I keep hitting some roadblocks in my coding knowledge. I have code that creates this table but the CSHOW column is coming out wrong.

```
| SHOW_DATE | SONG_ORDER | SHOW_ID |   SONG_NAME | SONG_ID | PREVDATE | CSHOW |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  07/19/13 |          1 |     899 | Song Name A |      51 | 04/10/13 |     7 |
|  07/19/13 |          2 |     899 | Song Name D |     568 | NEW SONG |     7 |
|  07/19/13 |          3 |     899 | Song Name C |     168 | 04/10/13 |     7 |
|  07/19/13 |          4 |     899 | Song Name E |      13 | 03/03/13 |     7 |
```

This is found by querying this data and code:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_songs
    (`song_id` int, `song_name` varchar(11));

INSERT INTO tbl_songs
    (`song_id`, `song_name`)
VALUES
    (51, 'Song Name A'),
    (368, 'Song Name B'),
    (168, 'Song Name C'),
    (568, 'Song Name D'),
    (13, 'Song Name E');

CREATE TABLE tbl_shows
    (`song_id` int, `song_order` int, `show_date` datetime, `show_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl_shows
    (`song_id`, `song_order`, `show_date`, `show_id`)
VALUES
    (51, 1, '2013-07-19 00:00:00', 899),
    (568, 2, '2013-07-19 00:00:00', 899),
    (168, 3, '2013-07-19 00:00:00', 899),
    (13, 4, '2013-07-19 00:00:00', 899),
    (368, 1, '2013-07-06 00:00:00', 898),
    (368, 1, '2013-07-03 00:00:00', 897),
    (368, 1, '2013-05-27 00:00:00', 896),
(51, 1, '2013-04-10 00:00:00', 895),
(168, 1, '2013-04-10 00:00:00', 895),
(513, 1, '2013-03-12 00:00:00', 894),
(13, 1, '2013-03-03 00:00:00', 893);
```

CODE

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.show_date,'%m/%d/%y') as show_date, a.song_order, a.show_id, 
b.song_name, a.song_id,  (
SELECT 
IFNULL(MAX(DATE_FORMAT(show_date,'%m/%d/%y')), 'NEW SONG')
FROM tbl_shows AS c
WHERE a.show_date > c.show_date and a.song_id = c.song_id
) As PrevDate, 
(
SELECT 
COUNT(*) FROM tbl_shows AS d 
where a.show_date > d.show_date
 ) As cShow 

FROM tbl_shows a, tbl_songs b
WHERE a.song_id = b.song_id 
AND a.show_id = 899
```

I'm looking to count how many shows have been played between the Show_Date and the PrevDate for each song.... and return that value for that row. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you. 
SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57d96/34

Comment: In your query, you have 4 rows with the same show_id. Are you expecting the rows to be counted even if the show_id's are the same?

Comment: I'm not looking to count the rows...I'm looking to count the shows between Show_date and PrevDate in mySQL, example for Song Name E there should be 5 shows since played, Song Name C should be 3 shows, etc. I have data points in the values which is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP?  You tagged php but I don't see any reference to PHP above.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

mysql_num_rows() will return the number of rows in the result (after you call mysql_query)

edit: I see you are trying to do it all in the SQL query.  You should set it up how you have the previous date, but use count on an additional query.  I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: after I query the data I am putting it on a website using PHP

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you'll put in in a website using PHP, use the mysql_num_rows() just like what Devon said.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

If you want to get the count in your query, you can use COUNT():

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

I think you can have one column to see the number of records in your query but I also think that it's not a good idea. I recommend you to use mysql_num_rows instead since you'll use PHP.

Comment: Counting rows is easy, what I'm trying to do is only count the shows played between show_date and prevdate for a certain songs....